Logged out redirection
If I press Enter using http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/ after logged out I am redirecting to http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/?next=/dashboard/.
How can I redirect to http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/ after logged out by press Enter ?

Does this answer your question? How to configure where to redirect after a log out in Django?

Both URLs are same? Just that the first one contains the URL to be redirected to after successful login. You can remove it like mentioned here
